# Adding a custom cell by UIButton

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to add a brand new custom cell with function of picking image from library and typing titles from text field, I have two view controllers in storyboard:

1. View controller of feed with picture and two of labels, all of these in table view.
2. Second view controller is responsible to add new image by picking image from library and creating two labels by textField

Two of them I connected into to one class (I am not sure is this legal). So my issue is that after picking image and typing labels and clicking button, the objects do not append in UI, but in print statement of arrays it does also.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,    UITableViewDataSource{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //        cardTableView.isHidden = true
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var titleTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func AddPurchase(_ sender: UIButton) {
        titles.append(titleTextField.text!)
        pictures.append(imageView.image!)
        descriptions.append(descriptionTextField.text!)
        print(titles)
        print(descriptions)
        print(pictures)

    }

    @IBOutlet var cardTableView: UITableView!

    var pictures: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "banan.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "pineapple.jpg")!, UIImage(named: "dragonfruit.jpg")!]
    var titles: [String] = ["Banana Paradise", "Pineapple island", "The Dragon's Fruit"]
    var descriptions: [String] = ["Hello", "Hello", "Hello"]


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return pictures.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cardCell", for: indexPath) as! CardCell

        cell.configure(picture: pictures[indexPath.row], title: titles[indexPath.row], description: descriptions[indexPath.row])

        return cell
    }

    //Add

    @IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let vc = UIImagePickerController()
        vc.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        vc.delegate = self
        vc.allowsEditing = true
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
}


extension ChatViewController:  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        if let imageShow = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey(rawValue: "UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage")] as? UIImage{
            imageView.image = imageShow
        }

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

I've tried to append image and text to array in button function.